# Generate summary from data using formula in excel

Tags: excel

I have data into "Data" sheet from where I have to match two columns and count the certain value which may be occur across various columns. Please find attached images.
I want create report which I added into "Summary" sheet, wanted to find values in table. Any help.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I got answer from other site:
In D2, formula copy across and down :

```
=IFERROR(1/(1/SUMPRODUCT(--(OFFSET(Data!$C$1,MATCH(1,(Data!$A$2:$A$64=$C2)*(Data!$B$2:$B$64=$A$2),0),,,3)=D$1))),"")
```